# Flutter : Open Page from page inside bottomnavigationview

Tags: dart, flutter

i want to open profile page from home page without press 'profile' button inside bottomnavigation item. 
Thanks for help.
this is a main class of my project. i put all page here and i already import all page here.

**MainClass**

```
int _currentIndex = 0;
    final List<Widget> _children = [
        HomePage(),
        MessagePage(),
        ProfilePage()
    ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('My Flutter App'),
     ),
    body: _children[_currentIndex],
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
       currentIndex: _currentIndex,
       onTap: onTabTapped,
       items: [
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
           title: new Text('Home'),

         ),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: new Icon(Icons.mail),
           title: new Text('Messages'),
         ),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.person),
           title: Text('Profile')
         )
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
```

and this my home page. this page same as profile and message page. i need to open profile page from home page without pressing profile menu in bottom. i just wanna press profile button inside home page.

**HomePage**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigation/profile_page.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Home Page"),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("GO TO PROFILE PAGE"),
              onPressed: (){

                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by directly calling the class name.
For example consider **Profile()** be the class extending statefull class.

**Home class**

```
....

int _index = 1;

  final options = [
    Text('Home'),
    Text('Message'),
    Profile() //directly call the class to load
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My flutter app"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: options.elementAt(_index),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.message),
            title: Text('message'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              title: Text('profile')
          )
        ],
        currentIndex: _index,
        onTap: _onTapped,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _index = index;
    });
  }
```

Similarly you can load other classes too.
hope it helped:)

Comment: i already have main_page, that contains bottomnavigation. inside home_page. there no have bottomnavigation.

Comment: This is for your main_page only. Just add your profile class name for loading the scene in your app.

Comment: `int _currentIndex = 0;
    final List<Widget> _children = [
        HomePage(),
        MessagePage(),
        ProfilePage()
    ];`
i already do this.

Comment: using the bootomnav bar. That is what it is meant for i.e to navigate with onetap.

Comment: i want to update my question.  hope you understand what i want. thanks so much for helping me.

Comment: i already put my code in question @john Wick. please review that.

Comment: You can use streams to pass data and use the StreamBuilder class to get the stream value. Also check the BLOC pattern which is used for async data handling. FlutterRx package make it more easier to handle the async calls.